# ASP.NET dynamic sub-menu is truncating text when scrolling arrow appears

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

I have a dynamic sub-menu that gets programmatically constructed in the code behind. Whenever a large amount of items are added, the scroll arrow appears to allow scrolling of the sub-menu, but when it does appear, it also seems to truncate the menu text because the sub-menu width is not correctly sized to accommodate the text.

The problem is not the scrolling itself; that is working the way I want it to. The problem is that the menu width is shortened and this is truncating the menu text when the scrolling arrows are presented for large menus.

This problem seems to be in IE7, because it is working fine in IE6, the width of the menu is of the appropriate size to fit the text. Has anyone experienced this before and how did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the menu in a div and set overflow:scroll on that, but that applies to the entire menu, not the drop-down part. You can't change the drop down part on the standard menu, but it you use the CSS Adapters (http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) you can change the size and scroll capabilities of the drop-down parts. However, this gives the standard scrolling - you see a scroll bar around the section and you have to scroll manually, it's really not a very nice experience. What you probably want is something that gives an arrow at the top/bottom to allow scrolling as you hover over it, to bring the items into view; this cannot be done without rewriting the menu control. If you need this functionality you might be best to look at a third party menu control, or even one of the ajax frameworks which might have something. jQuery...

Comment: I'm not saying the problem is with the scrolling. The scolling arrows are appearing for a large menu and I want it to appear for large menus. The problem is that when it does appear, it seems to be producing a smaller menu width that truncates the menu text.